# Creating and Defining base view for backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, extend

I am attempting to extend backbone views to add a basic implementation of a layout "skeleton". This will be used to piece together a page using the different components. The problem as listed below is the scope changes for all the nested object layout pieces. Could I create closures for all of these that point to the same scope or am I limited to a single object tier? Maybe I am thinking about it wrong?

```
    define(['backbone', 'underscore'
], function (backbone, _) {
    var base = backbone.View.extend({});

    _.extend(base.prototype, {
        sections: {
            head: {},
            body: {
                nav: {},
                main: {
                    header: {
                        title: "",
                        description: "",
                        inner_html: function () {
                            return this.render().el
                        },
                        menu_items: [],
                        changed: false,
                        scripts: function () { }
                    },
                    content: {
                        title: "",
                        description: "",
                        inner_html: function () {
                            return this.render().el
                        },
                        scripts: function () { }
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        items: [], // { id: "save", value: "Save" }, { id: "edit", value: "Edit" }
                        changed: false,
                        scripts: function () { }
                    }
                },
                footer: {}
            }
        }
    });

    return base;

});
```

Comment: Side-note: why are you extending Backbone's View with an empty object to use _.extend right afterwards?

Comment: So I can use backbone.view's properties and then add my own. Then I can extend my class so all my views will have 'sections'.

Comment: Nvm, I get what you are saying. I could just add my stuff in the initial extend.

Comment: Well, the extend method of Backbone uses _.extend and does a bunch of other stuffs. Furthermore, the static properties are also attached to your new class. So that means you can do [that](http://jsfiddle.net/zJuHL/).

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Actually, that's a piece of code I wrote for another question a while ago, and I'm always using it as a base so I don't have to bother including underscore + backbone in jsfiddle. But hey, you're welcome.

Comment: Also, about your problem, I guess there could be some way to include a recursive _.bind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like Marionette's Layout views and regions. You may not need to write this yourself. I often use the Layout,Regions, and specialized views from Marionette without the App and Module portions.

Comment: I have been reading about for a bit. I am gonna go with this route. It may require some rework in my app, but it does everything I need. I use kendo ui templates and I like how I can just override the renderer. The marionette.modules are also gonna be important as it wasn't something I was conceptually ready for when I started. What amazes me is, I have been doing most of this work myself; render events (pubsub), view and child view cleanup, composite views and collection views, etc... Glad you told me, fan of Derick Bailey anyway :)

Comment: I definitely get what you are saying. I wrote that same stuff over and over in several projects. I also used Justin Searls backbone-fixins a few times as well. https://github.com/testdouble/backbone-fixins But, I have found Marionette is a nice starting point for base classes and mixins of my own.

Comment: Agreed. I went with the approach of creating my own subclasses to manage a lot of the boilerplate stuff like child view management, but they were never great.  Marionette did what I tried to do but better.  When I switched, I got an instance productivity boost!